# SSAS - how to script the General settings? where are them stored? how can they be queried?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, security, ssas

I believe I am an administrator on server BIREPLON1 SSAS as you can see on the picture below.

[image]

These security permissions can easily be scripted.

this is an example:
apologies foe the horizontal scroll, but that's how it is.

```
<Batch xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine' Transaction='true'>
    <Alter AllowCreate="true" ObjectExpansion="ObjectProperties" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
        <Object />
        <ObjectDefinition>
            <Server xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ddl2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2" xmlns:ddl2_2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2/2" xmlns:ddl100_100="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2008/engine/100/100" xmlns:ddl200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200" xmlns:ddl200_200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200/200" xmlns:ddl300="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300" xmlns:ddl300_300="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300/300" xmlns:ddl400="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400" xmlns:ddl400_400="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400/400">
                <ID>SASBIDEV01</ID>
                <Name>SASBIDEV01</Name>
            </Server>
        </ObjectDefinition>
    </Alter>
    <Alter AllowCreate="true" ObjectExpansion="ObjectProperties" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
        <Object>
            <RoleID>Administrators</RoleID>
        </Object>
        <ObjectDefinition>
            <Role xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ddl2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2" xmlns:ddl2_2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2/2" xmlns:ddl100_100="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2008/engine/100/100" xmlns:ddl200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200" xmlns:ddl200_200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200/200" xmlns:ddl300="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300" xmlns:ddl300_300="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300/300" xmlns:ddl400="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400" xmlns:ddl400_400="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400/400">
                <ID>Administrators</ID>
                <Name>Administrators</Name>
                <Members>
                    <Member>
                        <Name>mycompany.CO.UK\BIUsersDEV</Name>
                    </Member>
                </Members>
            </Role>
        </ObjectDefinition>
    </Alter>
</Batch>
```

Is there a way to script the settings found on the "General" tab, as seen on the picture below?

otherwise,

where are these permissions stored?

how can they be queried?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The settings that you are looking for are stored in **<kbd>msmdsrv.ini</kbd>**

`\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS12.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP\Config\msmdsrv.ini`

or `<your Analysis service custom path>\OLAP\Config\msmdsrv.ini`

Note: Above path applies for Default installation.

Its a good practice to create a backup of that file, if you are changing any config value.